# iOS build crash on iPhone6 with latest update 12.4.3 when loading scene with Unity3D - Google Cardboard

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, google-vr

Our team is developing a Google VR app (aka Google Cardboard) with Unity 3D. The build crashes loading scene on iPhone 6 after updating to the latest available version of that device: iOS 12.4.3.

Notice we've tested and it's working perfectly on the previous versions. Specifically we've tested on iOS 11.4 and 13.4.4. It's also working well on the Unity editor and other iPhones released after iPhone 6 (6s, 7...)

We've called Apple, but they just suggest us to patch the bug because they don't know if they will fix it (or when).

The official Github issues tracker of GoogleVR for Unity3d has been archived, so we can't report the issue there either.

Do anybody was able to find out how to patch it?

Unity version: 2018.3.8f and GoogleVR: 1.190.1 (aka Cardboard)

Comment: It would seem then, the patching of it is down to you

Comment: @BugFinder if it only crashes on iPhone 6 with iOS 12.4.3, why do you think it's down to us? May you clarify your point please?

Comment: well if the googleVR has been archived, they gave up on it, so you would need to fix the issue..

Comment: @BugFinder yes, they say they are preparing it to open source it in the future. Anyway, we are asking here for help. I mean, it's obvious we need to find how to patch it, but we are asking if somebody has the same issue and found the solution! Doesn't it make sense for you?

Comment: SO wouldnt be a place to find a patch for a random code library..

Comment: @BugFinder as there are two options and the first option is not available anymore: https://developers.google.com/vr/community , we used the second option. What is the most correct place if not this one to ask this question in your opinion?

Comment: There doesnt have to be a place on the stack overflow network for you, some problems just need sorting by yourselves.. If you have found a bug in some software currently not supported, either find different software, or, as you have source, patch it yourselves.  If its going open source, you can then upload your fix when it does and get some kudos points from anyone else..  For the most part, problems with someones software should be taken up with them.